# Interviewing candidate for managerial position

Tags: interviewing

I work for a startup company. I found out that my current supervisor has tasked me to interview a candidate who could end up being my manager.

My current supervisor is on vacation but he left me a list of requirements for the position. I am familiar with interviewing people at my level (data engineers) but I have never interviewed people for leadership positions.

I can interview this person on his technical skills for the position but how can I tell if he is a good fit for our environment? How can I determine he and I will work well together, since I may have to report to him?

In our work environment, leadership is 100% approachable. From both founders of the company on down to department heads. I have never found a manager/supervisor unwilling to listen to issues. Issues are openly discussed and solutions hashed out. I personally enjoy the "family" atmosphere here at work.

What should I be on the lookout for in this interview? Red Flags?  Indications that this is a good fit?

Comment: Alan, your question seems quite broad. Perhaps you could narrow your question to some specific points of interviewing or qualities that your supervisor mentioned?

Comment: Entire books have been written on the subject.  Please narrow the scope of your question.  As it stands, it is too broad for an answer.

Comment: @RichardU Edited post. My apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @Alan could you add some details about the work environment?  It would help us answer

Comment: @Alan no problem, we try to help new arrivals to The Workplace.  Welcome.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm assuming the OP's not doing the sole interview, if they are, that's a bit worrying. I would expect the OP to be doing one of several interviews the candidate would be going through, trying to get a perspective from a potential subordinate. Hopefully the OP can clarify that though!

Comment: @Draken Correct. There will be four other interviewers. Not just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to gear your questions around the current environment.

If, as you said, that management is 100% approachable, then you want to phrase your questions to pull out his attitude towards being approachable.

"How would you deal with too many employee concerns?"

"How would you resolve a dispute between two valued employees?"

"An employee has requested time off to attend a wedding, but granting it would leave us short staffed, how would you handle it?"

"What is your personal philosophy for management?"

"Tell me a good joke"

et cetera.

The red flags to look for are anything that might indicate a lack of openness, a confrontational approach as opposed to a collaborative approach and anything that indicates that he is not approachable on a personal level.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Under most circumstances, yes.  But this is for a management position where they are supposed to be approachable and have a family atmosphere.  I've been asked this one myself, actually.

Comment: @RichardU Accepted. Thank you. I can't vote up since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I'm not sure what being able to tell jokes has to do with being approachable...?

Comment: "Tell me a joke" tests only a candidates joke telling ability. It says nothing about how approachable a person is. There are many examples of great comedians who, off-stage, were angry and unapproachable.